# "use strict" issue in Edge browser from angular 4

Tags: angular, use-strict

I am having trouble to resolve this issue which appears in Edge browser. Have tried manually removing "use strict" from my build, which did not help me out.

I am using the latest angular 4.3.6 in my application.

> ERROR TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

Comment: what is the build tool you are using?

Comment: I am using webpack as my build tool

Comment: in Build 41.16299.15.0 of Edge im not Faceing this problem, Older versions does throw the Error :(

Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not find any solution for this yet. But i found that, some of the issues were resolved when i don't use CSS property "flex-box".